# Container link with other container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have a docker compose with React app into nodejs js service container and mercure server into mercure container :

```
services:
  nodejs:
    build: 
      context: ./nodejs
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - mercure
  mercure:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: dunglas/mercure:v0.10.4
    environment:
      - PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=mercure_publisher
      - SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=mercure_subscriber
      - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
      - PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
      - MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES=cors_allowed_origins *
      - SERVER_NAME=":80"
    ports:
      - 3001:80
```

In my React app, i call mercure with url 127.0.0.1:3001
exemple :

```
const url = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:3001/.well-known/mercure', window.origin);
```

I need to call mercure service with name, exemple :

```
const url = new URL('http://mercure/.well-known/mercure', window.origin);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've answered your own question:

> I need to call mercure service with name, exemple :
>
> ```
> const url = new URL('http://mercure/.well-known/mercure', window.origin);
> ```

That's correct:

- You need to use the `mercure` hostname instead of `127.0.0.1`. The latter address is the loopback address and refers to "this container"; since the mercure service is running in a different container from your react app, it won't work. Using the `mercure` hostname is the correct solution.
- You need to connect to the `mercure` service on port 80, because that's the port on which it is listening. The `ports` directive (just like the `-p` argument to `docker run`) only effects ports that are published on the host; it doesn not control container-to-container communication.